# Python/ML code causing Ubuntu 20.04 to freeze and restart

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following python code:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
%matplotlib inline

from sklearn.model_selection import  train_test_split
import os, pathlib
data_base = 'data/predict_housing_price_data'
train_path = f'{data_base}/train.csv'
test_path = f'{data_base}/test.csv'
data_path = f'{data_base}/california_housing_train.csv'

assert(os.path.exists(data_path))
df = pd.read_csv(data_path)
df['median_income_to_house_value'] = df['median_house_value'] / df['median_income']
df['rooms_per_household'] = df['total_rooms'] / df['households']
df['bedrooms_per_room'] = df['total_bedrooms'] / df['total_rooms']
df['population_per_household'] = df['population'] / df['households']

train, test = train_test_split(df, test_size = 0.2)


df.info()

np.sum(df.isnull())

df.describe()

corr_matrix = train.corr()
corr_matrix['median_house_value'].sort_values(ascending=False)

sns.heatmap(corr_matrix, xticklabels=corr_matrix.columns, yticklabels=corr_matrix.columns)


#sns.pairplot(df)

train_copy = train
before_shape = train_copy.shape
print(train_copy.shape)
upper_bounds = {}
lower_bounds = {}
for key in train_copy:
    q25, q50, q75, q90 = np.percentile(train_copy[key], [25, 50, 75, 90])
    inter_quartile_range = q75 - q25
    upper = q75 + 1.5*inter_quartile_range
    lower = q25 - 1.5*inter_quartile_range
    upper_bounds[key] = upper
    lower_bounds[key] = lower
    train_copy = train_copy[(train_copy[key] >= lower) & (train_copy[key] <= upper)].reset_index(drop=True)

print(before_shape[0] - train_copy.shape[0], 'removed outliers')
    

train = train_copy.copy()

features = ['longitude', 'latitude', 'housing_median_age', 'total_rooms', 'total_bedrooms', 'population', 'households', 'median_income', 'rooms_per_household', 'bedrooms_per_room', 'population_per_household']
print(features)

target = ['median_house_value']

train_X, train_Y = train[features], train[target]

def vif(X, vif_lim = 10):
    import statsmodels.api as sm
    from statsmodels.stats.outliers_influence import variance_inflation_factor
    
    for i in range(len(X.columns)):
        
        l = [variance_inflation_factor(X.values, i) for i in range(X.shape[1])]
        s = pd.Series(index=X.columns, data=l).sort_values(ascending=False)
        
        if( s.iloc[0] > vif_lim):
            X.drop(s.index[0], axis=1, inplace=True)
            print("Removed",s.index[0],', VIF = ', s.iloc[0])
        else:
            break
    print("Remaining columns:", X.columns)

x_copy = train_X.copy()

vif(x_copy)
train_X = x_copy.copy()


#fit model
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error, r2_score
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score


folds = 5
lr = LinearRegression()
scores = cross_val_score(lr, train_X, train_Y, cv=folds, scoring='r2')
print(f'r2={np.sqrt(scores).mean()}')


lr = LinearRegression()
scores = cross_val_score(lr, train_X, train_Y, cv=folds, scoring='neg_mean_squared_error')
print(f'neg_mean_squared_error={np.sqrt(-scores).mean()}')

from sklearn.linear_model import Ridge

ridge = Ridge(alpha=0.1)

scores = cross_val_score(ridge, train_X, train_Y, cv=5, scoring='r2')
print(f'r2={np.sqrt(scores).mean()}')

from sklearn.linear_model import Lasso

lasso = Lasso(alpha=0.1)

scores = cross_val_score(lasso, train_X, train_Y, cv=5, scoring='r2')
print(f'r2={np.sqrt(scores).mean()}')

from sklearn.model_selection import validation_curve

ridge = Ridge(random_state=42)
param_name = 'alpha'
param_range=[0, 0.1, 1, 10, 50, 100, 200, 300, 500, 700]
scoring = 'neg_mean_squared_error'

scores = validation_curve(ridge, train_X, train_Y, scoring=scoring,cv=5,param_name=param_name, param_range=param_range)

train_score=[np.sqrt(-scores[0][i].mean()) for i in range(len(param_range))]
test_score=[np.sqrt(-scores[1][i].mean()) for i in range(len(param_range))]




fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,6))
plt.plot(param_range, train_score, label='Train')
plt.plot(param_range, test_score, label='Test')
plt.xticks=param_range
plt.title(f"Validation curve of {param_name}")
plt.legend()

lr = LinearRegression()
lr.fit(train_X, train_Y)

l = list(train_X.columns)
l.extend(target)

features_used = list(train_X.columns)
features_used.extend(target)

test_copy = test.copy()
test_copy = test_copy[features_used]

for c in test_copy.columns:
    print(c)
    test_copy = test_copy[(test_copy[c] >= lower) & (test_copy[c] <= upper)].reset_index(drop=True)

test_X, test_Y = test_copy[train_X.columns], test_copy[target]
print(train_X.columns)

train_mse = mean_squared_error(train_Y, lr.predict(train_X))
train_rmse = np.sqrt(train_mse)
print("Training error:", train_rmse)

print(test_copy.info())
y_pred = lr.predict(test_X)
test_mse = mean_squared_error(y_pred, test_Y)
test_rmse = np.sqrt(test_mse)
print("Testing error:", test_rmse)
```

### What I have investigated

#### Journalctl

It seems simple enough. However, when I run this code once or twice, it will cause my OS to completely freeze for 60 seconds and then restart itself.

When I check

```
journalctl
```

for time right before the crash (crashed at Oct 03 07:11:16 on the clock during the freeze), I see almost nothing significant; here is some output from seconds before the crash and right after:

```
Oct 03 07:08:13 luke-MS-7C75 tracker-store[9751]: OK
Oct 03 07:08:13 luke-MS-7C75 systemd[1904]: tracker-store.service: Succeeded.
Oct 03 07:09:08 luke-MS-7C75 gnome-shell[3800]: Error in cpuinfo: failed to parse processor information from /proc/cpuinfo
Oct 03 07:09:45 luke-MS-7C75 gnome-shell[3800]: Error in cpuinfo: failed to parse processor information from /proc/cpuinfo
Oct 03 07:10:16 luke-MS-7C75 gnome-shell[3800]: Error in cpuinfo: failed to parse processor information from /proc/cpuinfo
Oct 03 07:10:33 luke-MS-7C75 gnome-shell[3800]: Error in cpuinfo: failed to parse processor information from /proc/cpuinfo
-- Reboot --
Oct 03 07:12:37 luke-MS-7C75 kernel: microcode: microcode updated early to revision 0xf0, date = 2021-11-16
Oct 03 07:12:37 luke-MS-7C75 kernel: Linux version 5.15.0-48-generic (buildd@lcy02-amd64-043) (gcc (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.1) 9.4.0, GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.34) #54~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Sep 1 16:17:26 UTC 2022 (Ubuntu 5.15.0-48.54~20.04.1-generic 5.15.53)
Oct 03 07:12:37 luke-MS-7C75 kernel: Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-48-generic root=UUID=ba6e33b4-72c6-4fe2-be4e-d22fb9649dd4 ro quiet splash vt.handoff=7
Oct 03 07:12:37 luke-MS-7C75 kernel: KERNEL supported cpus:
Oct 03 07:12:37 luke-MS-7C75 kernel:   Intel GenuineIntel
Oct 03 07:12:37 luke-MS-7C75 kernel:   AMD AuthenticAMD
Oct 03 07:12:37 luke-MS-7C75 kernel:   Hygon HygonGenuine
```

ps. I also added acpi=off to grub bootloader because I saw something about that, didn't help.

#### Swap size & hardware

I also checked the available swap memory and system memory as well as the heat of my hardware. Nothing seemed out of line, memory was pretty much full and heat was baseline. CPU and Memory usage in System Monitor were normal.

#### Something strange

Here's where it gets pretty interesting. I run this code (typically) in Jupyter Notebook. If I run it manually, with python3 **code.py** then I get the same crashing error. But if I run it one cell at a time, I never crash. However, if I click the "restart the kernel, and re-run the whole notebook." button, it crashes reliably. However, if I run the code cell by cell from top to bottom, it never crashes...

Even **WEIRDER** is that if I had sleep(1) after every cell, then I CAN click that "restart the kernel,..." button and be just fine and I will *never* experience a crash doing it like that. If there is sleep(1) I can also run as python3 and it will never crash.

The crash also seems to happen towards the later stages of the run but if it were a specific piece of code or library why can I run them individually and have it work perfectly?

## Update

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import  train_test_split

data_base = 'data/predict_housing_price_data'
data_path = f'{data_base}/california_housing_train.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(data_path)
print('Iterated!')
```

This code reliably crashes my computer. My memory isn't maxed out on cpu or gpu and my swap space has a ton of space left. I have no idea why this is happening still. It also doesn't explain why I can run without issues if there is a sleep between each statement.

Comment: Please try to *isolate* the issue at the greatest possible extend, before posting here (we cannot do this ourselves). For example: remove all plotting code (which is anyway largely independent from the rest); is the problem resolved? Good, you have found the cause; Otherwise, you can *remove* the relevant code from here (along with a couple of tags) and continue with the next candidate removal - e.g. with the *inference* part of the code at the end etc... Otherwise, we have a wall of code and little to try ourselves.

Comment: Are you using anaconda? If so, update everything, and or try a new environment.  If not, you can install anaconda without messing up your normal python install, and retest the notebook.

Comment: I will work on both your suggestions and update.

Comment: added update to bottom @desertnaut

Comment: Great! See - wasn't that difficult, was it? Compare it with the wall of code above, and you see that you are now in a much better position to resolve it (although arguably you could remove more code, i.e. the sklearn import and the `print` statement, which should be irrelevant - probably the issue is at `pd.read_csv()`).

Comment: I suggest you now *remove* all your code before the update - it is just *clutter*; even your previous statement that "*The crash also seems to happen towards the later stages of the run*" does not seem valid now.